# Resizing a java BitSet

Tags: java, resize, bitset

I sub classed the BitSet class to add some additional methods. One of the is called "fold".
It splits the BitSet in 2 halves and "combines" them with an or.
(increases Information density)

This works but the size (1024) of the folded BitSet is still the original size.

Code:

```
    BitSet firstHalf;
    BitSet secondHalf;
    for(int i = nrOfTimes; i > 0; i-- ){
        firstHalf = this.get(0, this.size()/2);
        secondHalf = this.get(this.size()/2, this.size());
        firstHalf.or(secondHalf);
        this.clear();
        this.or(firstHalf);
    }
```

It's probably doable to return a new BitSet of desired length but only by creating a new smaller one for each iteration but still you would need to re-assign it (myClass = myClass.fold()). If you fold, there is no interest in the original version. The idea is to save space (memory and DB).

Is there a way to reduce the size of the current BitSet? (a "trick" I'm not seeing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's okay to do `myClass = myClass.fold()`, you don't have to worry about "saving space".

If there is no interest in the old object (i.e., no one has a reference to it) **the garbage collector will clean up the memory for you** anyway. It is well optimized for these kind of use cases.

This pattern is found in all immutable classes in the java library. Take for instance `str = str.substring(i);` or `bigInt = bigInt.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);` etc.

Comment: Thanks. So will do it this way. probably was thinking about optimization to early. These BitSets represent something and are used for in-memory search. Code needs to be able to handle several 100k easily. (Creation of these BitSets takes certain time hence they are stored in a DB so they can be re-loaded quickly).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you are correct, the `clear` method will clear all the bits but will not release any internal memory used to hold the bits.

For what it's worth: If you look at the source code of `BitSet`. The bits are hold in an internal array called `words`. The only place where this array is downsize is in the private `trimToSize()` method. This in turn is only called from `clone()` and `writeObject()`, but only if the size is **not** sticky -- i.e. if the `BitSet` was not created by calling the `BitSet(int nbits)` constructor.

Your suggested approach of creating a new `BitSet` and reassigning it is perfectly OK. The original version will be garbage collected anyway. The modified method could look like this:

```
public static BitSet fold(BitSet bs, int nrOfTimes)
{
    BitSet temp;
    while (nrOfTimes-- > 0)
    {
        temp = bs.get(0, bs.size()/2);
        temp.or ( bs.get(bs.size()/2, bs.size()) );
        bs.clear();
        bs.or(temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```